# Node.js embeding an async function in another async function gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I tried to embed an async function in another async function. Why do I get an error and how to solve it?

That's my setup:

helper.js

```
const express = require('express');

async function loginRoute (req, res) => {

    ...

}

module.exports = {
  login: async (req, res, next) => {

    try {
      async loginRoute(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).end();
    }

    next();

  }

}
```

Console Error:

```
async function loginRoute (req, res) => {
                                     ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at ...
    at ..
```

Or is there no need to do it twice?

Comment: I think you meant `await loginRoute(req, res);`

Comment: Please read a javascript tutorial, especially the syntax parts of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: You made a **typo**. A function declaration doesn't have `=>` in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define it like that. Do this

```
async function loginRoute (req, res) {

    ...

}
```

Or

```
const loginRoute = async (req, res) => {}
```

When you call the function, do `await loginRoute(req, res);`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this syntax:

```
const loginRoute = async (req, res) => {
  // do something
}
```

then

```
await loginRoute(req, res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either of two  ,you just can't combine arrow function with function declaration

```
async function loginRoute(req, res)
{

    //function declaration

}
```

or

```
let loginRoute = async (req, res) =>
{

    ... //function expression with arrow syntax

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use arrow function please write code like this

```
const loginRoute = async (req, res) => {

   ...

};
```